Safely Shoring Up a Roof During Patio Demolition and Reconstruction
I'm about to begin a project and am seeking recommendations for safely supporting a roof while performing structural work underneath.
I have a house built in 1971 with a raised wooden floor foundation and a crawl space underneath. The previous owner added front and rear patios, both of which are now collapsing in the center and need to be replaced.
The front patio is approximately 29 inches tall, 7 feet deep, and 19 feet long. It seems to have been constructed with a cinder block foundation around the perimeter, with wooden beams spanning the distance and concrete poured on top. Other than large rocks mortared to the side of the cinder block foundation around the entire porch, the porch is detached from the house itself.
Above the porch is a roof extending from the eave of the house, constructed with 2x4 rafters that are connected to the house using joist hangers. The roof is covered with asphalt shingles and sheathing material. The rafters extend to a beam supported by four posts, three of which are set into the concrete porch and tied into the wooden structure beneath the concrete. The beam and roof span the entire width of the house, approximately 33 feet.
I need to temporarily shore up the roof while I demolish the collapsing concrete structure, set new footings, erect 5 new posts, and install new beams. Eventually, I plan to tie the roof back into the new beams using strong ties.
My questions are:

What is the safest way to shore up the roof while I demolish the structure beneath it?

Am I missing anything in my plan, or is there anything I should be considering that I haven't mentioned?


My current plan: I plan to frame a temporary wall along the entire span of the roof to support it during the demolition. The temporary wall will have a double top plate, a double bottom plate, and studs spaced every 16 inches. Due to the work underneath, the temporary wall will need to sit out of plumb by about 2-3 feet.
The bottom plate will rest on dirt, with 2-foot steel concrete form stakes driven into the ground at an angle, both in front of and behind the bottom plate. I'll nail the bottom plate to the stakes, which will cross in an X pattern to secure it. The top plate will be attached to the roof using strong ties.
The goal is to complete the demo work as quickly as possible, install the new footings, beams, and posts, and eventually replace the concrete structure with a wooden deck.








Photos, diagrams or plans please

Yes, pics are essential here.

sounds likely much stronger than is needed

Your plan sounds reasonable, but I'm not comfortable saying more without seeing it. There could be critical aspects to the situation that we don't have.

can you replace the posts one at a time?

"safest way" Do you really want "kindergarten" safety level or is building site safety level enough?

I updated the post with pictures.

Often seen acrow jacks used to support situations like that.
